# Rangy v13alpha.804 lacks CssClassApplier module?

Tags: javascript, selection, textselection, rangy

thanks for Rangy! however, after severe testing (aaargg!) i discovered that

```
rangy.modules.CssClassApplier
```

returns false in .804, but returns true in previous version .772 .. What happened? Am i missing something?

-roelof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in there now as `rangy.modules.ClassApplier`.

I'm in the process of renaming that module to "ClassApplier" after realising that [the term "CSS class" is inaccurate](http://tantek.com/2012/353/b1/why-html-classes-css-class-selectors). I was intending to keep backwards compatibility so I'll patch `rangy.modules.CssClassApplier` back in there for the next version.

Comment: ok, thanks, i also discovered rangy.modules.ClassApplier .. i see you're rewriting the Rangy code into api.things - right?

Comment: @RoelofBerkepeis: How do you mean? I've tweaked module loading a bit with a view to supporting AMD but I don't think I've changed much else in the API.

Comment: i mean that the newest .804 rangy-cssclassapplier.js contains the code _rangy.createModule("ClassApplier", ["WrappedSelection"], function(api, module) { ... }_ but .772 contained the code _rangy.createModule("CssClassApplier", function(api, module) { api.requireModules( ["WrappedSelection", "WrappedRange"] ); ... }_ , so i concluded a new setup regarding the api-object.

Comment: @RoelofBerkepeis: That's the module loading changes I mentioned. It's a work in progress: finishing it requires me to look properly at AMD, so it may well change again.